# Проект C++ DirectX в проекте C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

Имеется следующее решение:

1) Первый проект написан на C# WinForms, имеется главное окно,
 MenuStrip и Panel.

2) Второй проект - это проект на С++ с directX api, в котором происходит отрисовка модели(грузится файл и отрисовывается в окне). Это dll.

Как работает приложение: по кнопке в menustrip загружается функция из dll, в которую передаётся *по ссылке*  дескриптор panel, размещённого в окне. Далее, в проекте с++ идет создание устройства, отрисовка, загрузка.  В этом же проекте я подменяю оконную процедуру на нужную мне(подвигать камеру, покрутить, классика).  По выходу из функции оконная процедура восстанавливается.
В целом всё работает замечательно(конечно требуется доработка, рефакторинг, но это пока не к спеху), кроме одного, неясного мне, бага. После отрисовки модели, если максимизировать окно, и после тут же его восстановить(надеюсь, я верно выразился), то при восстановлении окна сообщение WM_SIZE в оконной процедуре, располагаемой в dll(которая теперь привязана к panel) не отлавливается. Соответственно, перерисовка не происходит(перерисовка модели происходит при WM_SIZE, в нем вызывается соответствующая функция). Испробовал уже все, что только можно.

Кода прилично, минимальный пример предоставить не могу, он получится объёмный. Но сам по себе проект не такой уж и большой, разобраться можно быстро. Т.к. проект учебный, я могу приложить проект к сообщению, если кто-о вызовется посмотреть, натолкнуть меня на ошибку, которую я допустил. Спасибо большое заранее.

**P.S.: проект я сократил до минимума, там осталось только главное.**

Comment: Перехватите WM_SYSCOMMAND (в WindowProc) и для него делайте перерисовку (лучше плюс SC_RESTORE)

Comment: @nick_n_a делал и так тоже, и всё равно не ловилось...решил проблему немного другим способом. Задал контролу panel новое окно directX - ребёнком. И настроил стили. Всё прекрасно работает :)